# Flask variable dynamic url with html templates

Tags: python, flask

While writing some code to have pages dynamically update. I have had the issue of it trying to render pages.
The error is:

jinja2.exceptions.TemplateNotFound: /html/test.html

This is the code that finds and renders the page:

```
        # Open the user file to read from
        url = name
        url_file = open('projects.txt', 'r')
        lines = url_file.readlines()
        # check all lines for matching name
        for line in lines:
            saved_url, maintance, html = line.split("|")
            if saved_url == url:  # if url is the same. print info and display page. adding maintence check after
                print("url:", saved_url, " is in maintence:", maintance, " html template area:", html),
                if maintance == 'false':
                    return render_template(html)
```

Unsure of what would be causing this error or if flask just does not like reading a variable for the location of the template.

The template does exist. And trying this with /html/index.html lets this work.
*Note*: The rest of the code works. Just the very last line.

And I'm aware that using a database of any type would be better but for the moment this is what I have to work within.

**Edit**
So what the code is reading is `test|false|/html/test.html` from projects.txt.
When running debug the variable html is reading as a string. Its reading `/html/test.html` .
Point being, It should be passed as a string from that.

I'm just going to make a dynamicly updating area in the html for the projects as it seems that my original idea wont work.

Comment: Hi, welcome to StackOverflow! It looks like you're trying to render the file `test.html` which either doesn't exist or is not in the place Flask is looking for it (ie in the directory `html`)

Comment: Sorry I forgot to add. The test.html Does exist. And while using /html/index.html as a substitute it did work.

Comment: `return render_template(html)` - what's html?

Comment: Can you post an example of the string that would be stored in the html variable? Or even the first few lines of projects.txt

Comment: `return render_template('test.html')` - html file names are passed to render_template as strings, not objects